# Generating points on the surface of a wavy sphere in Python

Tags: python

I know generate points on a sphere surface isn't too hard, but I'm curious if there is any algorithm, python code, and formula that can be used for a wavy sphere (see following picture example). I'm trying to generate points on the surface of such wavy spheres. And every wavy spheres have different structures with each other.
[image: wavy sphere1]
[image: wavy sphere2]

Comment: You need a noise algorithm that could produce "perfect loop" noises. Take a look at [Perlin Noise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perlin_noise) and [this playlist from Coding Train](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qf4dIN99e2w&list=PLRqwX-V7Uu6bgPNQAdxQZpJuJCjeOr7VD), 3D Perlin Noise will fit perfectly for this problem. Create points of the sphere first and then adjust its distance from the center based on the noise value, I think this is too much code to put into an answer.

Comment: The information is useful, thanks a lot!